# How to render an HTML attribute from a Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to use the same partial view for create, edit, and details views, to avoid duplicating the fieldset structure for an entity.  Then, depending on which view renders the partial view, I would like to add a class of "read-only" to a div surrounding my fieldset and handle making the actual input fields read-only on the client, using css or jQuery, or whatever.  How can I specify from my Razor view that I need this class added to the "item-details" div?

```
<div class="item-details">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product Details</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DetailItem.ProductId)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DetailItem.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DetailItem.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DetailItem.Name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally have a variable on the model that would indicate if your data is editable, and use it like:

```
<div class="item-details @(Model.IsReadOnly ? "read-only" : "")">
```

If you don't have it on the model however, you can use the `ViewBag`. In your parent view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.IsModelReadOnly = true;
}
```

In your partial view:

```
<div class="item-details @(ViewBag.IsModelReadOnly ? "read-only" : "")">
```

Your html output for a readonly view would be

```
<div class="item-details read-only">
```

You can then access the div via jQuery and do what you need: `$(".read-only")...`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.[whatEver Property you are trying to show])